# Showing a substring of text that contains HTML

Tags: asp.net-core

I am implementing something similar to a blog engine, where on the entry page I would like to see a listing of my posts, and, for each, its title and a short piece of its body content.
This body content is HTML, and is stored in the database as a string, so, it's not enough to just show a substring of it, because it might break the HTML structure.
I guess the algorithm would be: render the string to HTML and extract only the first X characters of it.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Post>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
                </td>                
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var model = new List<Post>()
    {
        new Post(){ Title="asp.net core mvc",Body="<html><div><h1>The Model-View-Controller (MVC) architectural pattern separates an application into three main groups of components: Models, Views, and Controllers. This pattern helps to achieve separation of concerns. Using this pattern, user requests are routed to a Controller which is responsible for working with the Model to perform user actions and/or retrieve results of queries. </h1></div></html>"},
        new Post(){Title="asp.net core razor pages",Body="<html><div>Razor Pages is designed to make common patterns used with web browsers easy to implement when building an app. Model binding, Tag Helpers, and HTML helpers all just work with the properties defined in a Razor Page class.</div></html>"}
    };
    foreach(var item in model)
    {
        item.Body= Regex.Replace(item.Body, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", String.Empty);
        item.Body= item.Body.AsSpan(0, 30).ToString()+"...";
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I had already arrived to this conclusion. Will mark as the answer if no alternative arises.

Comment: For the regular expression I would probably use "<[^>]+>", what do you think?

Comment: Of course.For my regular expression,it is also avoid appearing useless space.